# Emoticons displayed as raw HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, emoticons

I am using the mattimo:emoticons package in Meteor (https://atmospherejs.com/mattimo/emoticons) to display emoticons. I am using this simple template to test it:

```
    <template name="test">
      {{parseEmoticons ":-)"}}
    </template>
```

which is displayed through the route "/test" like so:

```
    Router.route('/test/', function () {
      this.render("test");
    });
```

This should display a simple smiley, but instead I get the raw HTML in the browser:

```
    <img class="meteoremoticon" src="/packages/mattimo_emoticons/assets/images/emoticons/caritas_07.png">
```

How do I get the browser to render the HTML instead of just displaying the unprocessed HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pkg_spacebars):

> {{{content}}} - Triple-braced template tags are used to insert raw HTML. Be careful with these! It's your job to make sure the HTML is safe, either by generating it yourself or sanitizing it if it came from a user input.

So, try to use triple braces

```
<template name="test">
  {{{ parseEmoticons ":-)" }}}
</template>
```